# Is there a name for a "network overview diagram"?

Tags: terminology, diagrams

I have a highest-level diagram / map / picture of connected networks where internet is pictured as a cloud, some physical machines, firewall, switches etc which describe an overview of the "ecosystem" / at large scale.

Is there a name for such a diagram?

It might not make a difference that this particular diagram doesn't display many software servers, mostly physical machines and networks. In these diagrams if there is a database it is usually depicted as a cylinder (looks like a storage can).

It is not a sequence diagram, not a use-case diagram and not a class diagram. Is it even an UML diagram?

Comment: Architecture diagram?

Comment: Please note that this falls under the category of "[name this well-known concept with an objective answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6586/)."

Comment: Distributed Computing Environment Diagram...with DCE services include: Remote Procedure Calls (RPC),Security Service,Directory Service,Time Service,Threads Service and Distributed File Service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of a UML diagram for this, but in my experience this is simply called a "network diagram." I have seen probably hundreds of them throughout my career. While I have seen some variations on them, they typically look like this:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Network Diagrams: An Agile Introduction](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/networkDiagram.htm)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a network diagram :) Network diagrams can be any level of detail and you don't have to have every endpoint on the diagram. What you describe is typically a WAN or site-to-site diagram showing how traffic routes between sites, with each site actually representing an entire network of devices. According to this site, there is not a standard for representing network architecture in UML:

http://www.uml-diagrams.org/network-architecture-diagrams.html